# Trying to match Frequency-Gain chart in paper and not succeeding

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying to reproduce the chart on page 3 of [this paper](https://www.sisoft.com/uploads/SParameterCausality.pdf) for the transfer function:

- H(s) = 1/(1+jw/s0)
- where s0=-3x10^9
- or 1/s0=3.33e-10

I have [tried in a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NYBHJ9NUhC2K1cMzKDb_5hbxLJw6mNFjRy47SybeivQ/edit?usp=sharing) as the paper suggests and had to fudge things to make them a close match.

I used s0=2e-9 to get to -40dB at 5x10^10 Hz. It seems somewhat reasonable compared to my next attempt (s0 only differs by a magnitude and some change).)

My next attempt was in python:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

S1=signal.ZerosPolesGain([],[0.000000002],1)

win=np.arange(0,6e10,10000000)
w,mag,phase=signal.bode(S1,win)
mag[0] # produces 173.97940009
mag[-1] # produces -215.56157724 <- I assume these are in dB
```

The values in mag seem even more off to me. Does anyone have any suggestions of what I can try to get the same results as the author?

Comment: You can include the chart as a picture in your question. At a quick glance, the paper goes to f=5e10Hz, but you quote  5x10^8 Hz, and win seems to go to 6e10rad/s. As for your dB assumption, it's specified in the scipy manual.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I've fixed the quote and converted win to radians.

And then pressed enter before I was done editing.

win=np.arange(0,5e10,10000000)
win=win/math.pi<br>
S1=signal.ZerosPolesGain([],[0.000000000333333333333333],1)<br>
w,mag,phase=signal.bode(S1,win)<br>

mag[-1] is -204.03466528<br>
mag is returned in dB so it seems like I've still got an error/something I still don't understand in here.

Comment: You can keep editing to make sure it is all correct. Best not to leave it up to the patience of readers. I also suggest you include the plot. Something to check: mag[-1] is at what frequency (Hz) ?